# ReferenceError: "Drive" is not defined. (line 16, file "Code") in google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-realtime-api

When I try to use Google drive reference it always shows ReferenceError: "Drive" is not defined. (line 16, file "Code").

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've solves this error by go to:

**Resources** -> **Advanced Google Services** -> **Enable Drive Api**

[image]

Note: you need to Enable Drive Api in Google Console

Comment: thanks bro! here's the line of code `Drive.Files.insert(file, image, {ocr: true});`

Comment: @CotyEmbry Happy that it can help you. :)

Comment: In the "Advanced Google Services" you need to scroll down to see the drive. In the Google Console dashboard, go to "enable API and services", type "drive" in the field, enable it.

Comment: Unfortunately, enabling the Drive API in the dashboard didn't solve this for me.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Sour's answer:

If you have multiple libraries, it seems that you have to enable the Drive API in every Google Apps Script Project (not to be confused with a Google Cloud Project) that might use the Drive API, even if the actual call to the API occurs in a different Apps Script Project.

For example, say you have two Apps Script Projects, *Util* and *DoStuffWithSheets*. *Util* contains a function with a call to the Drive API. *DoStuffWithSheets* imports *Util* (by going to Resources -> Libraries). *DoStuffWithSheets* has a function that is triggered by an edit to a Sheet or whatever, and it calls the *Util* function that uses the Drive API.

It is **NOT** sufficient for the Drive API to be enabled in *Util*; it has to be enabled in *DoStuffWithSheets*.

This goes for Google Apps Script libraries which belong to the same Google Cloud Project in which the Drive API is also enabled. I haven't tested it for libraries which belong to different GC Projects.