# ReferenceError: "AdminDirectory" is not defined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

I am using a sample script to create a user but it keeps get this error
ReferenceError: "AdminDirectory" is not defined

```
/**
 * Adds a new user to the domain, including only the required information. For
 * the full list of user fields, see the API's reference documentation:
 * @see https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert
 */
function addUser() {
  var user = {
    primaryEmail: 'liz@mydomain.com',
    name: {
      givenName: 'Elizabeth',
      familyName: 'Smith',
    },
    // Generate a random password string.
    password: Math.random().toString(36),
  };
  user = AdminDirectory.Users.insert(user);
  Logger.log('User %s created with ID %s.', user.primaryEmail, user.id);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReferenceError: "Drive" is not defined. (line 16, file "Code") in google app script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43838960/referenceerror-drive-is-not-defined-line-16-file-code-in-google-app-scr)

Comment: While not about `AdminDirectory`, the linked question is about another google advanced service that needs to be activated before use

Answer (score 7):

You need to enable the API in 2 places.

1. Inside the Google Script Editor, go to Resources > Advanced Google Services and enable the Admin Directory Service.

[image: Advanced Google Services]

2. Next go to Resources > Google Cloud Platform Project > Enable API and Services. Search for Admin SDK and enable the API.

[image: Admin SDK]

Answer (score 0):

For those using the new interface for Apps Script, normally you would add a service in the editor itself (Files, Libraries, **Services**):

[image: Add a service in the editor interface of Google Apps]

Unfortunately the AdminDirectory service does not seem to be available in the new interface (as at July 2022). For the next few months while the classic editor is still available, you can click "Use classic editor".

From there it's as Amit explained, `Resources` menu → `Advanced Google services...` then turn on `AdminDirectory` next to `Admin SDK API`:
[image: Advanced Google services...]
[image]

Once you've added the service you can go back to the new interface to continue editing and it will show up in the expected spot:
[image: AdminDirectory service in new interface]